# Does not display an image! Django

Tags: python, django, image, django-models

> Does not display an image!

image is exists, dut django didn't display any images on page, how to fix this?

## this is my models.py

```
class All_Images_Of_The_Series(models.Model): 
    to_series                               = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None)
    image_of_all                            = models.ImageField(upload_to="previews/previews_for_series/", default=None,width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    is_poster                               = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    is_active                               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    width_field                             = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height_field                            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp                               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Active: |%s| and Poster: |%s| " % (self.is_active, self.is_poster)

    class Meta:
        ordering                            = ["-timestamp"]
        verbose_name                        = 'All_Images_of_the_Series'
        verbose_name_plural                 = 'All_Images_of_the_Series'
```

## this is my views.py

```
def homeview(request, *args, **kwargs):
    full_path                       = All_Images_Of_The_Series.objects.all()
    context = {"full_path":full_path,}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

## this is my template

```
<div class="col-sm-3 right-side">
                <div class="new-movies-block">
                    <a class="header" href="#/new/">
                        <div class="title">Новинки</div>
                    </a>
                    {% for one_to_one_path in full_path %}
                        <div class="movie-spacer" ></div>
                        <a class="new-movie" href="{{ one_to_one_path.to_series.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ one_to_one_path.to_series.eng_name }}">
                            <div class="title-info">
                            {{ one_to_one_path.to_series.season_of_this_series.number_of_season }} сезон {{ one_to_one_path.to_series.number_of_series }} серия 
                            </div>
                            <div class="date">{{ one_to_one_path.to_series.timestamp_rus }}</div>
                            <img src="{{ one_to_one_path.image_of_all.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

## If you look at the element code, the images, then in the line "src" there is a path to the picture, and it's working! But does not display the picture itself!

```
<img src="/media/previews/previews_for_series/1.png" class="img-responsive">
```

## this is error in console(f12)

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/previews/previews_for_series/1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `full_path`?

Comment: Are you able to see `image` inside related model's admin page? This might be related to static and media path settings for development server.

Comment: It turns out when I turn this path "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/previews/previews_for_series/1.png" then writes that the page is not found, but it's in the folder, in the one in which it should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Do this !

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^series/', include("serials.urls", namespace='series')),
    url(r'^', include("serials.urls", namespace='homeview')),



]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick thoughts, you don't show me the things you might need to work. For example if this if for development on the urls you need this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development and on your settings you may need something like that

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

I hope it helps

Best

Comment: Dude I'm not so stupid as not to take it away!
STATIC_ROOT     = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")
MEDIA_URL       = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT      = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_cdn")

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't added the media to your urls.py

```
From django.conf import settings

# your stuff

if settings.DEBUG:

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    })
)
```